# Python project structure clarification

Tags: python, linux

I have some scripts which I am organizing on a Linux server and I was thinking about creating a package for them (to share with my peers and make me more familiar). I want to make sure that I am clear on how this should be set up, since I am reading a lot about the Linux FHS http://www.pathname.com/fhs/. I think I have the general structure set up properly, but I am not certain about where to place the raw data, configuration files, and logs.

```
├── ~/bin/project_1
|   ├──/project_1 
│   │     ├── extract.py
│   │     ├── transform.py
│   │     ├── load.py
│   │     ├── __init__.py
|   ├──MANIFEST.ini
|   ├──README.rst
|   ├──setup.py
|   ├──.hgignore
```

- Where do my raw files go? My 'extract' script is querying for data every 30 minutes and generating a .csv file from various tables and databases (so there is a whole sub-folder structure to the raw files). I would not version control these files, but they are required for the transform.py script. Do they belong in this 'package', or should they be saved in another Linux directory?
- Where do my config files go? Should they be in ~/.config, or should I have them saved in this project structure? Some of my configurations are very general (used by several projects) and some are very specific to this project. I also have YAML and .py configuration files (Python ones are functions which I use often across many projects).
- Are logs saved within the package as well?

Comment: The data is separate from the code right?  If so then it should be somewhere else.  We set the data location as a configuration entry - often it is on a different drive or across the network/internet.

Comment: yes, it is separate. it is just the input/output files that the code uses or produces. I assume logging files would follow the same logic. What about configuration files? There are certain functions I use a lot and then of course the basic configurations about file paths, SQL engines, etc.